# Can I setup a network to share info without internet access?

Tags: networking, configuration, router, ethernet

I'm a new IT student and I want to setup a network to help me learn. Would buying a router and connecting computers via ethernet to the router work to set up a small mini network? Even if the router doesn't have internet access? I live with my parents and they already have internet but don't want me using it to try stuff in case I mess stuff up which is understandable. I can't afford to buy internet myself to practice so could I just get a router and connect the computers and set up permissions and groups and stuff that way? Or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  This is called a LAN or "Local Area Network".